# would it sound weird to ask for a professor to be as a permanent reviewer of a journal or conference?

Tags: peer-review

In my current work, we organize a CS conference every year, and we also have a journal in the CS field. However, we are currently facing a problem with some reviewers. On few occasions, we have a couple of reviewers who rejected the sent paper, saying they have not been appointed for the current year. However, they have acted as reviewers in previous versions of our conference. The question would be if it would be sound weird to ask a reviewer if he would like to form part as a permanent reviewer of the conference or journal. Are there any suggestions about how to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: There are long-term editors in journals. Long-term reviewers is not something I heard of in many journals, although Frontiers seems to have some kind of model like that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem odd at all. You can simply ask a "good" reviewer if they are willing to review again in the future. I suspect many will say yes and some will fail to respond.

When you ask, you can also ask for subjects/topics that most interest them. This would ease the work of the program committee in the future, as they would be a bit less likely to send requests that are unlikely to be fulfilled.

Another approach, used by some CS folks is to put up a page with received papers, perhaps just titles, and send out a broad appeal to previous reviewers (and others, perhaps) asking if they are interested in any of the papers.